# Angular universal. Dynamic routes are not rendered server-side

Tags: angular, routes, server-side-rendering, universal

I have problem with Server-side rendering dynamic routes with angular universal.

for example:

{ path: 'room/:slug', Component: RoomDetailsComponent }

will not be server side rendered.

{ path: 'room/first-room', Component: RoomDetailsComponent }

will be server side rendered.

I found some solutions for this, like fetching the routes from back-end service. I think there should be better, less hackier way of doing this

Comment: You cant have the same route with dynamic and static paths because it will collide. Change it to another thing, like
`{ path: 'rooms/:slug', Component: RoomDetailsComponent }`
and
`{ path: 'first-room', Component: RoomDetailsComponent }`

Comment: I am not using both at the same time. It was shown just as an example. If I use first one it doesn't work. second one works.

Comment: Ahh got it. I post a working stackblitz with the same example, please let me know if it help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are missing a property int the RouterModule declaration, because that should work as expected.

Here I create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fhyjek) that you can download and test it out with `npm run dev:ssr` (it has that same example)

As you can see in the picture, the dynamic parameter is rendered on server side (as its returned in the doc response `<body>`)
[image: param rendered in server]

Comment: First of all thanks for spending time on my problem!
In your example, the parameter that is provided for the dynamic route is rendered by javascript, on the client side. I need that to be rendered on server-side.
maybe I am missing something?

Here is the html  code (body part) returned by the server, when I proved as parameter '123': 
--
<body></body>
--
as you see, the body is empty. contents of body are rendered client side.

Comment: Thats weird because it is rendered on the server side, even if you run the `dev:ssr` command and enter the page in your browser with JS disable, I see the parameter passed in the page

Comment: Do not test the stackblitz on the site itself (as its only rendered with angular (not universal) ), to tests it download the project as ZIP, and install it locally

Comment: You are Absolutely right! Now I need to find out what is different about my code.

Comment: I found an issue. the page had an extra guard included in the routes... Thank you very much for your time once again